# pfsockopen thread-safe?

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, concurrency

I'm writing a PHP site which connects to a Java server to get data. It does this via a socket. To improve performance I'd like to use [`pfsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php) to connect to the server, so a new connection (with costly handshake) doesn't have to be opened for every request.

What I can't find in the documentation though, is this thread safe? If PHP is executed in multiple threads, does each thread get its own socket? I'll probably be running PHP as Apache module or as FastCGI.

Comment: Personally, I think I'd approach this by writing a separate connection pool daemon, and then connect to that connection pool via normal `fsockopen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes. If you're using a thread-safe SAPI (e.g. IIS), then `pfsockopen` will be safe to use.

Having said that, PHP is very rarely actually threaded.

- The Apache module, `mod_php` only works with the prefork MPM, i.e. one process per request. In this configuration there will be no benefit of using `pfsockopen`, as the entire process is cleaned up after each request.
- CGI similarly starts a new brand process for each request.
- FastCGI is one process per request, but is able to re-use processes.
- PHP-FPM uses a pool of processes, but is still single-threaded with respect to a single HTTP request.

Answer (score -2):

To save you some time you may want to look at this function made for parallel processing in PHP:

http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254

Comment: The link is dead.